# running more than 150000 test cases in soapui

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I am trying to run 150,000+ test cases within my test suite in ReadyApi(which involves making a Rest Request to a given API.) , however I always run into Heap memory problem which halts the test execution. 
I have tried everything on this link : http://readyapi.smartbear.com/soapui/working/improving_memory_usage to reduce memory consumption but still it runs out of memory. Increasing heap space might not be an option because of limited resources I have on my machine.
Current heap size is 4GB and permSpace is 500MB that is already allotted to ready API.

Answer (score 1):

SoapUI has known problems with memory handling.

With that many test cases, you should consider breaking everything up into multiple projects. The testcase runner has to be restarted for each project, and will therefore start with new memory footprint.